# Mongodb distinct records from last record not from first

Tags: php, mongodb

In mongodb php, I need to get a distinct list of records based on one field but the search should start from the last record.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you expect them to be listed in order of discovery by backwards? Also there really is no such thing as a "distinct record". There is only "distinct field values" or combination of fields.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Actually I have used this:

$collection->distinct( 'field_name' );

It returns the field values by searching the documents from first to last document. But I need them to get the distinct results from last document to first, so that I can get the recent five distinct values for the field.

Answer (score 1):

[db.collection.distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) doesn't sort records and doesnt work with a paginated data set, and it's not given the way it searches for distinct values: any order you see is incidental and could change with implementation or access plan.